# How do I search for code fragments that are punctuation? For example, how do I search for the strings ||: or ->?

Tags: support, search

How do I search for code fragments that are punctuation?  For example, how do I search for  **`||:`** or **`->`** ?  Is there a way to search for these sorts of things in StackExchange?

**Here's what I've already know:**

**Google** can find it.  See:
https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=-wXbXviUD4ri-gSNgKDoCA&q=%7C%7C%3A&oq=%7C%7C%3A&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoOCAAQ6gIQtAIQmgEQ5QJQnRFYxRVg1xhoAXAAeACAAZsBiAG1A5IBAzAuM5gBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXqwAQY&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwi4_pPAmOzpAhUKsZ4KHQ0ACI0Q4dUDCAg&uact=5

Google's results:

> ...
> [Which is more idiomatic in a bash script: `|| true` or `|| :`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78408/which-is-more-idiomatic-in-a-bash-script-true-or)

---

But both **[StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/590983/bash-suffix)** and **[DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/)**, can't seem to find these.  (I think DuckDuckGo can't find it because StackExchange can't find it.  [DuckDuckGo says they use Stack.. as one of their sources](https://duck.co/ia), but I'm not sure about just how this works.)

Comment: I don't think this should have been closed.  For one, the only answer given to the other question suggested by the closer, does NOT even answer that question.  This really is an outstanding problem, and closing this question is NOT the way to fix it.